# Query two tables and create columns from values to enable sort

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have data in the wp_post and wp_post_meta WP database: one contains a unique entry for "workshops" and the second contains meta data relating to each workshop. The tables look like this:

```
WP_POST TABLE

| post ID   | post title    | post type | post content etc.
|---------------------------------------------------------
|   1       | workshop 1    | workshop  | cooking with apples
|   2       | workshop 2    | workshop  | cooking with pears
|   3       | workshop 3    | workshop  | cooking with bananas

WP META TABLE

| post ID   | meta key      | meta value    | etc.
|---------------------------------------------------------
|    1      | summary       | apples        | ..
|    1      | date          | 20100518      | ..
|    1      | duration      | 1 hour        | ..
|    2      | summary       | pears         | ..
|    2      | date          | 20100623      | ..
|    2      | duration      | 1/2 day       | ..
|    3      | summary       | bananas       | ..
|    3      | date          | 20101111      | ..
|    3      | duration      | all day       | ..
```

I've been playing around with queries.

```
SELECT post_title, post_date, post_type, meta_key, meta_value, post_content
FROM wp_posts as post INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as meta ON post.ID = meta.post_id 
WHERE post.post_status = "publish" AND post.post_type = "workshop"
```

This query gives me one table that looks like this.

```
| post ID   | post title    | post type     | meta key      | meta value    | etc.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    1      | workshop 1    | workshop      | summary       | apples        | ..
|    1      | workshop 1    | workshop      | date          | 20100518      | ..
|    1      | workshop 1    | workshop      | duration      | 1 hour        | ..
|    2      | workshop 2    | workshop      | summary       | pears         | ..
|    2      | workshop 2    | workshop      | date          | 20100623      | ..
|    2      | workshop 2    | workshop      | duration      | 1/2 day       | ..
|    3      | workshop 3    | workshop      | summary       | bananas       | ..
|    3      | workshop 3    | workshop      | date          | 20101111      | ..
|    3      | workshop 3    | workshop      | duration      | all day       | ..
```

What I need to do is sort on the meta key value "date" but I'm not sure of the best way to do this. Can I sort by "meta value" for the "meta key" date?

I *think* I need the CREATE a table like this for that to be possible but have no idea how to do that, or even if that's the required approach.

```
| post ID   | post title    | summary   | date      | duration | etc.
|--------------------------------------------------------------
|   1       | workshop 1    | apples    | 20100518  | 1 hour
|   2       | workshop 2    | pears     | 20100623  | 1/2 day
|   3       | workshop 3    | bananas   | 20101111  | all day
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort on the date just using a `join`:

```
select p.*, d.meta_value as date
from wp_post p join
     wp_meta d
     on d.post_id = p.post_id and d.meta_key = 'date'
order by d.meta_value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregation to show meta data information in different columns for each post like

```
SELECT p.post_title, 
  p.post_date,
  p.post_type,
  p.post_content,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'summary' THEN m.meta_value ELSE NULL END) summary,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'duration' THEN m.meta_value ELSE NULL END) duration,
  MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'date' THEN m.meta_value ELSE NULL END) `date`
FROM wp_posts as p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as m ON p.ID = m.post_id 
WHERE p.post_type = "workshop" AND p.post_status = "publish"
GROUP BY p.post_title, 
  p.post_date,
  p.post_type,
  p.post_content
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'date' THEN m.meta_value ELSE NULL END), '%Y%m%d')
```

To order your data set with meta data value you need to cast it as a date object first by using [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d8e06/6)